# php database field as hyperlink

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I have a mySQL database that has a web address field that is a type: text. When it shows up on my web page I would like it to be clickable as a hyperlink.

I have code around the field to "show if not empty" and can't figure out how to wrap it as a hyperlink.

Here's my code:

```
<?php if($row_rsEvents['weblink'] != "") { ?><span class="webAddress"><?php echo $row_rsEvents['weblink']; ?></a></span><br><?php } ?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your stored urls looks like: `http://...` or `<a href="http://.."...` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `<a>` after your opening `<span>`,

```
<?php 
if($row_rsEvents['weblink'] != "") { ?>
    <span class="webAddress"><a href="<?php echo $row_rsEvents['weblink']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rsEvents['weblink']; ?></a></span><br>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This worked. My urls are all stored without the http://  All I had to was add that to the <a href="   and it works perfectly.

Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $weblink = $row_rsEvents['weblink'];  
  if($weblink != '') { 
    echo "<span class=\"webAddress\"><a href=\"$weblink\">$weblink</a></span><br>";
  } 
?>
```